# What probability would I use in a negative binomial distribution to say the expected number of false identifications per true identification?

Tags: probability, classification, negative-binomial-distribution

I have binary classifications made by some model, and I know the truth. From this, I can calculate the confusion matrix and all associated values: true positive rate, true negative rate, false positive rate, false negative rate, sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall, positive predictive value, negative predictive value, etc. (I know some of those have the same meaning just under different terms.)

What might be valuable for a project of mine is saying how many false identifications of an event we can expect in order to have $R$-many correct identifications. If we can get a million correct identifications while only crying wolf (incorrect identification) once, that sounds pretty good. If we have a trillion incorrect identifications for every million correct, however (so a million-to-one), that does not sound so good.

It sounds like I want the expected value of a negative binomial distribution, with some probability parameter $p$ and another parameter $R$ of how many true positives I want to achieve.

That $R$ parameter is straightforward enough to understand. However, what probability value would be used to calculate this expected value? Is that value derived from the confusion matrix? (It seems like it would have to be.) Is it one of the common values I listed above?

My suspicion is that I should take $p = \text{TPR}$, possibly $p = \text{PPV}$. Then the performance calculation I would do is the expected value of a negative binomial: $R\left(\dfrac{1-p}{p}\right)$.

(This is not the place to argue about classification vs estimating tendencies. Regardless of what we might think about the advantages of the latter, not every system worth analysis gives tendency estimates that can be analyzed through log loss or Brier score. Sometimes, the stick either gives one line or two, the shepherd either comes into town hollering about a wolf or doesn't, the dreaded "check engine" light comes on or not, etc.)

Comment: I didn't intend to self-answer until I had thought about this for a few hours, though I am open to an answer that explains why my self-answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**YOU WANT THE POSITIVE PREDICTIVE VALUE (PRECISION)**

Reading between the lines (which I concede is easier to do when I'm the one who wrote the question), you want to know how many times you will predict category $1$ only to have the outcome turn out to be category $0$ for $R$ number of instances of predicting category $1$ and having it really turn out to be category $1$. Therefore, the probability parameter in the negative binomial distribution is $P(Y = 1 \vert \hat Y = 1)$. This is the positive predictive value.

Potentially worth considering is how many times you will predict category $1$ only to have the outcome turn out to be category $0$ for $R$ number of instances of predicting category $1$ and having it really turn out to be category $1$, compared the the same value for some kind of benchmark model, such as randomly making categorical predictions based on the overall probability of each category occurring. [I have advocated elsewhere for comparing to a benchmark of always predicting the majority category](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605450/is-the-proportion-classified-correctly-a-reasonable-analogue-of-r2-for-a-clas) (typically coded as $0$), but such a model's positive predictive value conditions on the impossible event of $\hat Y = 1$, which never occurs when every prediction is $\hat Y = 0$. The positive predictive value of this random predictor is simply the overall probability of category $1$.

$$
\left. 
\left[\dfrac{
1 - \text{PPV}
}{
\text{PPV}
} \right]
\middle/ 
\left[\dfrac{
1 - P(Y = 1)
}{
P(Y = 1)
}\right] \right.
$$

That value $R$ for the number of correct classifications per number of expected misclassification is the same in both the numerator and denominator, so it cancels out.